# Is this measure a possible correct choice in a data warehouse cube?

Tags: data-warehouse, cube

I have this simple Data Warehouse schema:

```
Flight (ID, pilot, aircraft, airport)
Pilot (ID, name, surname, flight hours)
Aircraft (ID, model)
Airport (ID, name, city)
```

- Flight.pilot references Pilot.ID
- Flight.aircraft references Aircraft.ID
- Flight.airport references Airport.ID

Flight is going to be my **fact** table.

Then I'm going to have three **dimensions**:

1. pilotage (involving Pilot table)
2. vehicle (involving Aircraft table)
3. departures (involving Airport table)

One **measure** can be flights' number, obtained by count(ID) on Flight table.

In the following picture, you can see the star schema I've just described.

[image: Star Schema]

My question is: does it make sense choosing **flight hours** (which is a column of a table - Pilot - taking part in one dimension - pilotage -) ?

And, more in general, if it is possible/conceptually correct choosing as a measure a column which **is not** in the fact table.

So, in short, does a measure for a data warehouse cube HAVE TO BE from the fact table? Or also columns from dimensions' tables can be chosen?

Many thanks if you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense choosing flight hours (which is a column of a table - Pilot - taking part in one dimension - pilotage?

What else can flight hours take part in?  You're only measuring flight hours for the pilots.  You could (should?) measure flight hours for the aircraft, but you have no aircraft flight hours input for your warehouse.

Do the users of your warehouse want to know flight hours for pilots?  If so, then your Pilotage table becomes a de facto fact table for flight hours.

It would be more logical for a real warehouse to sum flight hours from the flights themselves, rather than have a lump sum for the pilots and the aircraft.  You're going to have to update the pilot flight hours every time you load the warehouse

> Is it possible/conceptually correct choosing as a measure a column which is not in the fact table?

Yes.  The rule is, if your users are going to query on the column, include it in the data warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

### It depends.

Gilbert is right about the main meal of the answer - your flight hours is on a per-pilot basis, so don't go trying to measure it vehicle, or you'll double (or triple, or quadruple...) your numbers because you only have a many-to-many relationship to those dimensions via your Flight fact table.

However, if your fact is non-summable (e.g. "average flight hours of the pilots who fly each vehicle") suddenly it does make sense again.

Now I'm most experienced with SQL Server SSAS models - in those situations I would typically create this as a calculated measure, and it would live in the Flight measure group - when you're making measures like these you have to be very specific about what relationships you're using, and how the aggregation is performed. In this case, the measure would actually cease to be "on the dimension" and would actually be "on the fact" (even though it was calculated by referencing the dimension). Happiness and best practice is resumed.

If you're not able to do that, however, it's really not the end of the world - if it works and makes sence in your context, then it works and makes sense in your context, there's not a lot else that comes in to it. Most of the DW best practices are just about warning you to make sure that it *does* work make sense in your situation.

So go figure out how you want to use it, and see if you can do that with your existing model.